# ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

Tags: oracle, exception, ora-08177

I have a very simple code using ADO.NET which throws ORA-08177 exception. I am not sure what's wrong with this. I am trying this on a windows vista machine which has oracle 32 bit client installed. My compile option for visual studio is set to x86 platform.

```
Dim connection As OracleConnection = Nothing
Dim transaction As OracleTransaction = Nothing

Try
    connection = New OracleConnection("Data Source=ora10;User Id=userid;Password=passwd;")
    connection.Open()

    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable)

    Dim inputStream As New System.IO.FileStream("Dummy.xls", IO.FileMode.Open)
    Dim fileLength As Integer = CType(inputStream.Length, Integer)
    Dim input(fileLength) As Byte

    Try
        inputStream.Read(input, 0, fileLength)
    Finally
        If inputStream IsNot Nothing Then inputStream.Close()
    End Try

    Dim deleteSql As String = "DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE Version = 'v1' "

    Dim cmd As New OracleCommand(deleteSql, connection, transaction)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO TABLE1 (VERSION, DATA) VALUES (:VERSION, :DATA) "
    Dim insertCmd As OracleCommand = New OracleCommand(insertQuery, connection, transaction)
    insertCmd.Parameters.Clear()
    insertCmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.Text
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":VERSION", "v1")
    insertCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":DATA", input)

    insertCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    transaction.Commit()

Catch
    If transaction IsNot Nothing Then transaction.Rollback()
    Throw
Finally
    If transaction IsNot Nothing Then transaction.Dispose()
    If connection IsNot Nothing AndAlso connection.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then connection.Close()
End Try
```

Important thing to note: (I am not sure if they are connected) but I do not face this problem if I uninstall latest windows updates from my machine.

Has anyone faced this or have any clue about what is going on here?

Edit:-

I have some progress where I have found out that this problem occurs only when we have blob column type in question. for simple columns it works fine.

Other details (not sure if that makes a difference)

I am working on 64 bit windows vista business machine. 
I have installed 32 bit oracle client for windows vista (since 64 bit oracle client does not work on vista).
I am compiling my project for a x86 (32 bit environment) in visual studio.
And this is a console application and I know that nobody else is hitting the database at this time. so there cannot be multiple transactions.

And I do not see this problem if I uninstall latest windows update. (KB963027, KB967190, KB959426, KB960225, KB960803, KB952004, KB956572, KB958687, KB958690, KB958481, KB958483, KB943729)

Answer (score 29):

You are using a serializable transaction which waits for some other transaction locking the same table to `ROLLBACK`.

If this other transaction does not rollback but commits instead, you will get this error.

The scenario seems to be as following:

1. `Alice` opens her browser session which calls `DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE Version = 'v1'`

   - `Bob` opens his session which calls `DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE Version = 'v1'` after `Alice` did it but before she commited.

   `Bob`'s transaction waits since `Alice` locked the rows with `Version = 'v1'`

   - `Alice` commits her transaction
   - `Bob`'s transaction fails with `Cannot serialize access`

To work around this, set `TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL` to `READ COMMITTED`:

```
transaction = connection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted)
```

In this case, `Bob`'s query will be reissued after `Alice` commits her changes, as if `Bob`'s transaction were started after `Alice`'s one was committed.

**Update**

Could you please post a trace of your connection?

To do this, issue this command right after connecting:

```
(New OracleCommand("ALTER SESSION SET SQL_TRACE=TRUE", connection, transaction)).ExecuteNonQuery();
```

, then look in `$ORACLE_HOME\admin\udump` for a fresh `*.trc` file

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am facing this problem when I am running this using a console application and I know there is no one other than me hitting that database.