# ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction in spring batch using oracle

Tags: oracle, spring-batch

I am using spring batch. I have more 10 batch processes running same database connection. I have run these batches using spring scheduling. But it shows below error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: PreparedStatementCallback; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?)]; SQL state [72000]; error code [8177]; ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1539)
        ........
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
        .....
 Caused by: Error : 8177, Position : 0, Sql = INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (:1 , :2 , :3 , :4 ), OriginalSql = INSERT into BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION) values (?, ?, ?, ?), Error Msg = ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

     at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:636)
        ... 53 more
```

I have configured Spring batch below like:

1. application.properties:

   ```
   spring.datasource.url=myurl
   spring.datasource.username=mydbName
   spring.datasource.password=myPassword
   spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

   spring.batch.job.enabled=true
   spring.batch.job.chunk.size=10


   # 0 */2 * * * ? --> 2 minutes
   batch-schduled-time=0 */2 * * * ?
   ```
2. MyBatch job

   ```
   @Component
   @RequiredArgsConstructor
   @Slf4j
   public class MyJob {

      private final MyTrxSummaryRepo approvedTrxSummaryRepo;
      private final MyApprovedTransactionRepo corpApprovedTransactionRepo;

      private final MyTransactionViewRepo allApprovedTransactionViewRepo;


      private final ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1;
      private final WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1;



      private final PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
      private final JobRepository jobRepository;



      @Value("${spring.batch.job.chunk.size}")
      private Integer chunkSize;



      public Job createEft(){

          String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

          return new JobBuilder(id, jobRepository)
                  .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                  .start(step1())
                  .build();

      }



      private Step step1(){

          return new StepBuilder("step1", jobRepository)
                  .<MyTrxSummery,MyTrxSummery> chunk(chunkSize, transactionManager)
                  .reader(new ReaderStep1(approvedTrxSummaryRepo,corpApprovedTransactionRepo))
                  .processor(batchProcessorStep1)
                  .writer(batchWriterStep1)
                  .build();
      }




      }
   ```
3. BatchBean

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class BatchBean {
       @Bean
       public ProcessorStep1 batchProcessorStep1() {
           return new ProcessorStep1();
       }

       @Bean
       public WriterStep1 batchWriterStep1() {
           return new WriterStep1();
       }

     }
   ```
4. MyTrxSummery Entity & repository:

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "mySummeryTb")
   @Data
   @Setter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class MyTrxSummery {
       @Id
       @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_REFERENCE")
       private String transactionReference;
     .........

   }

   @Repository
   public interface MyTrxSummaryRepo extends JpaRepository<MyTrxSummery, Long> {

       @Query("myquery.....")
       List<MyTrxSummery> getAllTransaction();

       MyTrxSummery findByTransactionReference(String transactionReference);

       @Modifying
       @Query(" update.....")
       public void updateApprovedTrxSummeriesByTransactionReference(String transactionReference);


       @Modifying
       @Query(" update......")
       public void updateSegmentedTransaction(String transactionReference);


   }
   ```
5. MyTransaction Entity & repository::

   ```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "CORP_APPROVED_TRANSACTION")
   @Data
   @Setter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class CorpApprovedTransaction {

      @Id
      @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_ID")
      private Long transactionId;
      ............
    }
   ```

   ---

   ```
   @Transactional
   @Repository
   public interface MyTransactionRepo extends JpaRepository<MyTransaction, Long> {

      @Query("select....")
      List<MyTransaction> findSegmentedTransaction(String transactionReference);

       @Modifying
       @Query("update ..")
       public void updateMyTransactionByTransactionReference(String transactionReference);


    }
   ```
6. ReaderStep1, ProcessorStep1 & WriterStep1

   ```
      @Slf4j
   public class ReaderStep1 implements ItemReader<MyTrxSummery> {

      private Iterator<MyTrxSummery> iterator;

      public ReaderStep1(MyTrxSummaryRepo myTrxSummaryRepo, MyTransactionRepo corpApprovedTransactionRepo) {

          List<MyTrxSummery> list = myTrxSummaryRepo.getAllTransaction();
          if(!list.isEmpty()){

              this.iterator = list.iterator();
          }
        }
      @Override
      public MyTrxSummery read() {

          return (iterator != null && iterator.hasNext()) ? iterator.next() : null;
       }  
     }
   ```

   ---

   ```
    @Slf4j
    public class ProcessorStep1 implements ItemProcessor<MyTrxSummery, MyTrxSummery> {



      @Autowired
      private MyTrxSummaryRepo approvedTrxSummaryRepo;

      @Autowired
      private MyTransactionRepo corpApprovedTransactionRepo;

       @Override
      public MyTrxSummery process(MyTrxSummery item) throws Exception {
           ......
        }

       }
   ```

   ---

   ```
   @Slf4j
   public class WriterStep1 implements ItemWriter<MyTrxSummery> {

      @Override
      public void write(Chunk<? extends MyTrxSummery> chunk) {
         ........
         }

       }
   ```
7. ScheduledJobBean

   ```
   @Component
   @Slf4j
   public class ScheduledJobBean {

      @Autowired
      JobLauncher jobLauncher;

      @Autowired
      MyJob eftJob;

      @Scheduled(cron = "${batch-schduled-time}")
      public void perform() throws Exception
      {

         try {
              JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(eftJob.createEft(), new JobParameters());

          }catch (Exception ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace();
          }

       }
    }
   ```

What is the wrong with my code...

Please help me to solve the problem....

Comment: Check this answer, in case it is useful to you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/785765/ora-08177-cant-serialize-access-for-this-transaction

Comment: @ORA-01017 thanks for your reply where I need to add TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL to READ COMMITTED

Answer (score 0):

Found on ORACLE support site:

"Concurrent inserts into a table with index using serializable transactions
could lead to an index split that the transaction tries to re-read and cause an error ORA-08177

fix:
Insert a smaller number of rows (e.g commit more often)

-OR -

Catch the error code in the application and re-try the operation again

-OR-

this can be fixed by implementing "rowdependencies" during normal table creation."